# Static member functions that are const with respect to static variables

Tags: c++, constants, static-methods, static-members

In C++, how do you declare a static member function of a class to be `const` with respect to the **static** member variables of that class?

Consider the following simple example.

myclass.h:

```
class myclass
{
    myclass()
    {
        myint = 0;
    }

    ~myclass() { }

    int myint;
    static int my_static_int;

    void foo(const int yourint) const;
    static void bar(const int newint );
};
```

myclass.cpp:

```
myclass::my_static_int = 0;

void myclass::foo(const int yourint) const
{
  if (yourint <= myint + my_static_int)
     std::cerr << "yourint  <= myint + my_static_int";
  else
      std::cerr << "yourint  >  myint + my_static_int";

  bar( yourint );
}

void myclass:bar(const int newint)
{
  my_static_int = newint;
}
```

main.cpp

```
...
myclass A;
A.foo(4);
A.foo(4);
..
```

The output would be:

```
yourint  >  myint + my_static_int
yourint  <= myint + my_static_int
```

Clearly, `bar` can be used **within `const` member functions** to change the static member *variables* of the class and thus change the result of **const** member function `foo`.

Can you declare `bar` to be const  with respect to `my_static_int` ?

Comment: There is no way to do this, and you misunderstand the meaning of `const`. `const` only means that the function won't modify any non-`mutable` _member variables_, not that it will "have the same output" every time you call it. For instance, what if you had a `static` variable in a `const` member function and incremented it on every call and returned it? It would still be `const` but return a different value every time.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Exactly.  I asked the question because there does not seem to be a way to differentiate "constant" static member functions from "non-constant" static member functions, where the "constant" is with respect to the static member variables.

Comment: @SethCarnegie And no, I did not fail to understand the meaning of `const`.  I actually demonstrated my understanding in the question.  On the contrary, you evidently failed to read my question, as your "comment" merely proposed merely another example of what my question is asking.

Comment: @Seth: it is impossible to drive more than 100 km/h, it is impossible for hummingbirds to fly, and even assigning to variable with an ungrokkable name, is impossible. i have proved this rigorously by noting that i can't imagine how to do it.

Comment: @MatthewParks no, text that you edited out implied that `const` shouldn't change anything in the class, which is wrong. That's what I was referring to when I said you misunderstood `const`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have proved rigorously that there is no way to declare `bar` to be const with respect to a static variable by noting that the standard doesn't provide such a declaration. Whether or not the _effect_ can be simulated is irrelevant to the fact that there is no such declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original code (I only tidied up the formatting):

```
class myclass
{
    myclass()
    {
        myint = 0;
    } 
    ~myclass()
    {}

    int myint;
    static int my_static_int;

    void foo(const int yourint) const;
    static void bar(const int newint );
};
```

In this class everything is `private`, **inaccessible**, by default: it is unusable.

That is one example why it is so important to post *real code*.

You then ask:

> “Can you declare `bar` to be `const` with respect to `my_static_int`?”

Yes, but there is no direct syntax for that.

You will have to use the existing language features.

They are adequate to the task.

```
class something
{
private:
    int my_int;
public:
    void bar( int const newint ) const;
    something();
};

class myclass
{
private:
    int myint;
    static something;
public:
    void foo( int const yourint ) const;
    ~myclass() {}
    myclass(): myint( 0 ) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can you declare bar to be static with respect to my_static_int ?

No.  C++ has not provided such a mechanism.

> This deeply bothers me because one would assume that multiple calls to
>   const member function foo would not change anything in the class

You should not assume that.  A const method may modify static variables, because those variables are not part of the *instance* that is being declared const.

It could also modify variables marked `mutable`.  Or members that have had their const-ness removed with `const_cast`.

And `const` functions can observe or modify variables outside of the class, so you should never consider a `const` function to behave the same way every time it's called.  You could have a `const` function return `rand()` for example.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c) to better understand the meaning of `const` in C++