# C++ const iterator in Vector

Tags: c++, overloading

I am a newbie to C++. So, please bear with me. I was looking into the implementation of the `std::vector` class. I found the following 2 different implementation of the `begin()` method. I understand that the first one returns a RW iterator and the second one returns a read-only iterator. I thought that mere difference in return type is not enough for function overloading. How does this work then?

```
iterator
begin()
{ return iterator(this->_M_impl._M_start); }

const_iterator
begin() const
{ return const_iterator(this->_M_impl._M_start); }
```

Comment: One is `const`, the other isn't. That's enough for overloading.

Comment: It's the standard library, [not STL](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/). You can just refer to `std::vector`.

Comment: Changed to std:;vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is `const` and the other isn't. The `const` version will be called for `const std::vector` objects while the other is called for non-const `std::vector` objects. Also note that this also applies to `const` and non-const references and pointers.

More info on `const` methods and overloading:

- [Meaning of "const" last in a C++ method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration)
- [What's the deal with "const-overloading"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-overloading.html)

Also relevant:

- [How many and which are the uses of "const" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The implicit "this" parameter is const in the second method. This is enough to distinguish them in overloading.