# Why is a constant value possibly computed at runtime and not by the compiler?

Tags: c++

I am reading Bjarne's *A Tour of C++* and he has this example in section *1.6 Constants*.

```
constexpr int dmv = 17; // dmv is a named constant
int var = 17; // var is not a constant
const double sqv = sqrt(var); // sqv is a named constant, possibly computed at run time
```

My question is related to his comment on the last line

> ... possibly computed at run time

From looking at the code, the value `var`, a numeric literal of `17` isn't going to be changed anywhere in the code. Why is it not evaluated at compile time by the compiler?

I saw this [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771146/can-the-compiler-not-determine-whether-a-variable-is-const-by-itself) when looking and it makes sense that `const` is used for semantics and more for the programmer than the compiler. But my main question is:

**Can the compiler not optimize this and if not is it because it is too much to ask of the compiler to optimize?**

**EDIT:** The part of the compiler I would like to optimize is to compute `sqv` since `var` is not changed anywhere in the program.

Comment: Note the word "possibly" in your quote.  The C++ language simply doesn't specify whether this value will be computed at runtime or compile time.  If you wrote your own C++ compiler, you could decide when this value is computed.

Comment: What part of `int var = 17;` do you want the compiler to optimize?

Comment: The std::sqrt will be constexpr in C++26 ... until then there are no way how you get compile time expression from sqrt. That does not mean compiler may not optimize it, but standard can't require it in any manner.

Comment: @Eljay, I added a comment

Comment: Whereas `sqv` is **not** a constant expression, compiler might, with as-if rule, optimize code to not call `sqrt` at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can the compiler not optimize this

It *may* be able to do it, but it's not required to be able to do it (until C++26 where `std::sqrt` has been made `constexpr`).

Even in C++11 mode, both `g++ 13.2` and `clang++ 16` optimize this program

```cpp
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    constexpr int dmv = 17;            // dmv is a named constant
    int var = 17;                      // var is not a constant
    const double sqv = std::sqrt(var);
    return static_cast<int>(sqv);
}
```

into this assembly

```
main:
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
```

Comment: Is the compiler really required to evaluate `std::sqrt` at compile time if it's `constexpr`? I'm pretty sure that it's merely allowed to do constant folding, but unless it's used in a context where constant expressions are required, it isn't forced to use `constexpr` evaluation.

Comment: @JanSchultke No, but a `constexpr` function is required to _be able_ to do it. It doesn't have to do it in all situations though, but if it's not able to do it, then it can't be used in situations where a constant expression is required, like in template parameters or `constinit` variables etc.

Comment: Could you clarify what the assembly means? Return a value of 4?

Comment: @heretoinfinity Exactly. It's calculated the result at compiletime even though its not required by the standatd.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the compiler not optimize this

It can in some situations, like this one. In fact, [`std::sqrt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) will be `constexpr` in C++26, so you will be able to do something like this:

```
constexpr int var = 17;
constexpr double sqv = sqrt(var);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6e7f6xs9P)

Note: GCC 13.2 apparently accepts this code even with `-std=c++11`. Clang 16.0 does not.

In your example, since `var` is not `constexpr` or even `const`, and `sqrt` is not yet `constexpr`, the call is not *required* to be made at compile time. However, if the compiler figures out that the value of `var` at the time of the call to `sqrt` is always `17`, then it could also optimize the call because `sqrt` is a pure function. It would not go against the standard.

Comment: gcc marks ("as extension") several mathematical functions as `constexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

> a numeric literal of 17 isn't going to be changed anywhere in the code. Why is it not evaluated at compile time by the compiler?

What may or may not be evaluated at compile time is not 17, but the result of `sqrt()` of 17. A compiler may be smart enough to know what this mysterious function from the standard library named "sqrt" does, and evaluate the result of `sqrt(17)`, and then insert the actual, raw, numerical value you get from applying the `sqrt` operation to 17, into the code. Or, the compiler may not know that, and generate the code that calls `sqrt`, here.