# Not sure what a constant function is in c++

Tags: c++, function, constants

The assignment is to create a constant function `getArea()` that returns the area of a rectangle.

```
double getArea() {
    return width * height;
}
```

Is this it?

Do I put const after the parameters?

I don't really understand what I'm being asked.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c

Comment: Please go through this discussion . It will answer your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration

Answer (score 6):

In C++, a function becomes const when const keyword is used in function’s declaration. The idea of const functions is not allow them to modify the object on which they are called.

```
double getArea() const    {
    return width * height;
}
```

const after the (empty) argument list in the function declarations. indicates that getArea() function do not modify the state of a object i.e. data member of a object.

Please refer this link for more explanation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389602/Constant-Member-Functions-Are-Not-Always-Constant

Answer (score 3):

```
double getArea() const 
   {
     return width * height;
   }
```

const keyword is used when the user doesnt want to modify or change the values of that variable or function.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the built-in data types (`int`, `double`, `char`, etc…), class objects can be made `const` by using the `const` keyword. All `const` variables must be initialized at time of creation.

Once a `const` class object has been initialized via constructor, any attempt to modify the member variables of the object is disallowed, as it would violate the constness of the object. This includes both changing member variables directly (if they are public), or calling member functions that sets the value of member variables.

`const` class objects can only call `const` member functions. A `const` member function is a member function that guarantees it will not change any class variables or call any non-const member functions.

**SOURCE :** [leancpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/)

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what to do to make the function const, but it does provide some background that addresses the question's *"I don't really understand what I'm being asked."* - nice!

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
class ClassType
{
int x;
public:
ClassType(int _x) : x(_x) {}

int GetX() { return x;}
};

const ClassType object(20);
object.GetX();
```

This will fail to compile, since the `object` is const (readonly). But `GetX` is not marked `const` (readonly). `length()`, `size()`, `IsOpen()` are example of methods that may be called from a read only object. Hence the class should facilitate such (const) functions for const object.

You generally don't create const object, but you do pass them like:

`void foo(const ClassType& obj);`

Therefore, the `GetX` function should be:

```
int GetX() const { return x;}
```

`const` make a promise or a contract that *this function doesn't modify this object*.