# Difference between function returning by reference and const function returning a const value

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, constants, return-type

I was making a class for arrays to work as stacks and encountered upon two types of functions to return the top element. I cannot understand the difference between the two and how the compiler decides which one of the two to call. Beloww is the code for the two.

```
T & getTop() {                //function 1
    return arr[top - 1];
}
const T & getTop() const {   //function 2
    return arr[top - 1];
```

the 'top' variable points to the current empty cell in the array and T is the generic datatype.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your stack is called `stack`.

```
stack<T> s;
/*do something with it*/
s.getTop(); //will call the non const version
std::as_const(s).getTop() //will call const version
```

And similarly:

```
const stack<T> s;
s.getTop() //const version
```

So, if the type of the variable is not const, it will call non const version. Otherwise it will invoke const version.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find an easier explanation than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c) for reference but in a few words for this specific case looks like is for tell to others methods won't change the logical state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

A `const T&` reference doesn't allow to modify the referenced data. Notice that the second `getTop()` method is declared as `const` too to specify that the method doesn't modify the state of the instance on which this is called.

Two implementations are required to allow getting the top element from a context in which the instance that contains the array is `const` and at the same time allowing to modify the top element in contexts in which it's not `const`.

This is part of a bigger concept named *const correctness*, you can get additional info about it [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness), specifically:

- [What does “const X& x” mean?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#ref-to-const)
- [What is a “const member function”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns)
- [What is the relationship between a return-by-reference and a const member function?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#return-const-ref-from-const-memfn)