# const method on c++ language

Tags: c++, class, methods, constants

I remembered, from university, that const method can not changes fields. 
I am returning to C++ now, and I have written simple program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int square;

public:
    Box(int a, int b)
    {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }
    const void showSquare(void) const
    {
        cout << this->a * this->b << endl;
    }

    const void setDim(int a, int b)
    {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Box b(2, 4);
    b.showSquare();
    b.setDim(2, 5);
    b.showSquare();
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

In my case const method can change fields of class?
How is it possible?

Than you in advance.

Comment: `const void setDim(int a, int b)` isn't a proper signature for a  const method. That would be `void setDim(int a, int b) const`.

Comment: `showSquare()` uses `const` to indicate not changing the "fields".   `setDim()` uses `const` to show that the return value of the function doesn't change (which is meaningless, but permitted, when returning `void`) but that is something unrelated to whether the function changes "fields".

Answer (score 1):

`setDim` in your question is not a `const` method. The method's return type is `const void`. Since the method returns `void`, the `const` really makes no difference.

If you want the method to behave like a `const` method (*a method not supposed to change the state of the object*), move the `const` to the end of the signature

```
void setDim(int a, int b) const 
    {
       // do read only operations on the object members.
    }
```

[How many and which are the uses of “const” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c) would be a good refresher.

Answer (score 0):

const void is the return value which is const not the const this pointer which cannot change the member data:

```
class A
{
    public:
        void show()const // this pointer here is constant so this method cannot change any member data or Call any other non-const member
        {
            a = 0; // compile time-error 

            setValue(7); // also compile time error: `error C2662: 'setValue' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const class A' to 'class A &'`
            cout << a << endl;
        }

        const void setValue(const int x)
        {
            a = x; // ok
        }

        private:
            int a;
};
```